# How do I add a constraint to a contour plot in matlab

Tags: matlab, mathematical-optimization

I am doing an optimization problem where I need to find the minimum surface area of a can to give me at least 400 cm^3 of liquid subject to some constraints on dimensions. I have already created a contour plot of the surface area but as the title says, I do not know how to add the constraint that (pi/4)*D^2*H <= 400. Here is the code I already have:

```
clear all;
clc;

%set constraints
%g1 and g2
D = linspace(3.5,8,100);
%g3 and g4
H = linspace(8,18,100);

%set objective function
[X,Y] = meshgrid(D,H);
f = pi*((X.*Y)+(X.^2/2));

%plot isolines
contour(X,Y,f,'Showtext','on');
xlim([0,10])
ylim([5,20])
hold on
xline(3.5) %g1
xline(8)   %g2
yline(8)   %g3
yline(18)  %g4
xlabel('Diameter [cm]')
ylabel('Height [cm]')
```

Comment: You can specify [an array of levels](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/contour.html#mw_21efb7a2-23ab-4a46-b7ec-e13f5c70117e) to display on the contour plot. This is defined in term of the function value, i.e. `f = [n1, n2, n3 .. nx]`.

Comment: Yes, but how can I specify that I only want the levels where the constraining function is greater than or equal 400? Sorry if the answer is obvious, I am new to this

Comment: `contour(X,Y,f, [400, 500, 600])`, note that your question states <=, but now you have asked for the opposite :)

Comment: The issue is that the lines at which the function f is equal to 400 is different from the line at which the constraining function is equal to 400. For example, the constraining function is  g = (pi/4).*X.^2.*Y and when this function is =400, the original function f is about 300

Comment: you cannot achieve this with a single contour plot, the contour value is specifically related to the function value. You can try to overlay the constraint function on the same plot, to achieve this, I recommend using a different line format to make the intent clear.

Comment: Is there a way to "fill in" the graph in the area where the function g is less than 400 so that the contour lines of f in that area cannot be seen?

Comment: probably, but this is fundamentally the same as overlayed plots.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to substitute NaNs in your objective function where the constraint is not satistified.

```
clear all;
close all;
clc;

%set constraints
%g1 and g2
D = linspace(3.5, 8, 100);
%g3 and g4
H = linspace(8, 18, 100);

%set objective function
[X,Y] = meshgrid(D, H);
f = pi*((X.*Y)+(X.^2/2));

g = (pi/4).*X.^2.*Y;
constr = g <= 400;

f1 = f;
f1(~constr) = NaN;

lvls = 100:25:600;

figure
hold on
% Original contour
subplot(1, 2, 1);
hold on
contour(X, Y, f, lvls, 'ShowText', 'on');
xlim([0, 10])
ylim([5, 20])
xline(3.5);
xline(8);
yline(8);
yline(18);
xlabel('Diameter [cm]')
ylabel('Height [cm]')
title('Original')

% Modified
subplot(1, 2, 2)
hold on
contour(X, Y, f1, lvls, 'ShowText', 'on');
xlim([0, 10])
ylim([5, 20])
xline(3.5);
xline(8);
yline(8);
yline(18);
xlabel('Diameter [cm]')
ylabel('Height [cm]')
title('Modified')
```